# Scala bound type parameter and reflection

Tags: scala, reflection, type-parameter

Could the following Java code:

```java
public <T extends Enum<T>> T foo(Class<T> clazz) {

  return clazz.getEnumConstants()[0];
}

public void bar(Class<?> clazz) {

    if (Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
        System.out.println(foo(clazz.asSubclass(Enum.class)));
    } else if (String.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
        System.out.println("Meow");
    }
}

bar(MyEnum.class) // prints the first value of MyEnum
bar(String.class) // prints Meow
```

be translated to Scala:

```scala
bar[MyEnum]()
bar[String]()
```

`Enum` is just an example of a class that follows the `T extends Wrapper[T]` pattern, and `foo` could have simply returned the name of the class (or perform any other kind of logic which requires reflective data that is only available in my "`Wrapper`" class).

I tried to make it work in Scala with `TypeTag` but failed; I got all sort of compilation errors, such as this:  `inferred type arguments [?0] do not conform to method foo's type parameter bounds [E <: Enum[E]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is quite likely a better way to do what you *actually* need, but:

```
import language.existentials
import reflect.ClassTag

def foo[T <: Enum[T]](implicit ct: ClassTag[T]) = ct

def bar[T](implicit ct: ClassTag[T]) = {
  val clazz = ct.runtimeClass

  if (classOf[Enum[_]].isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
    println(foo(ct.asInstanceOf[ClassTag[A] forSome { type A <: Enum[A] }]))
  } else {
    println("not a enum")
  }
}
```

Comment: I was just editing my answer with the "literal translation" but since you posted it I'll leave it to you :) +1 for the existential type though, maybe it's what he wanted to know

Comment: Yes! I tried something similar, and my `asInstanceOf` had a simple `Class[_ <: Enum[_]]` (i'm actually calling a Java method that requires a `Class`), but I knew it won't work and that I need a better existential type representation (as explained [here](http://www.drmaciver.com/2008/03/existential-types-in-scala)), but I was too lazy to fix it :p

Answer (score 1):

You can try a typeclass approach, so that everything is resolved at compile-time, no reflection involved:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

trait DoSomething[T] {
  def apply(): Unit
}

object DoSomething {
  implicit def enumDoSomething[E <: Enum[E]](implicit ct: ClassTag[E]) = new DoSomething[E] {
    def apply() = println(ct.runtimeClass.getEnumConstants()(0))
  }

  implicit object stringDoSomething extends DoSomething[String] {
    def apply() = println("Meow")
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  def foo[A](implicit doSomething: DoSomething[A]) = doSomething()

  foo[java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit]
  foo[String]
}
```

This way you don't have an if-else and you have a better separation of concerns.

if you want a "default" case, you can have a catch-all implicit.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

trait DoSomething[T] {
  def apply(): Unit
}

object DoSomething {

  implicit def enumDoSomething[E <: Enum[E]](implicit ct: ClassTag[E]) = new DoSomething[E] {
    def apply() = println(ct.runtimeClass.getEnumConstants()(0))
  }

  implicit object stringDoSomething extends DoSomething[String] {
    def apply() = println("Meow")
  }

  implicit def catchAll[T] = new DoSomething[T] {
    def apply() = {
      println("test") // some default case
    }
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  def foo[A](implicit doSomething: DoSomething[A]) = doSomething()

  foo[java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit] // prints NANOSECONDS
  foo[String] // prints Meow
  foo[Long] // prints test
}
```

If you're interested in how scala finds implicits, [take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits)

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but isn't what I asked for; I probably wasn't clear enough. `bar` type parameter must not be bound (simply `A`), and it must use `foo` which must have such bound type parameter. Moreover, your `bar` method won't compile with `String` (as in my example).

Comment: Oh ok, I see now, let me try something else

Comment: 1) It doesn't compile for me. Have you tried it? 2) I'm looking for a way to do that without changing `foo` as much (my `foo` = your `enumDoSomething`).

Comment: Umh yes I did O_o Let me check it -> It works, have you imported ClassTag? I edited the answer to add the import. I copy-pasted exactly what you see in the answer and it runs and prints what's expected

Comment: Are you on scala 2.10 by any chance? That could be why.

Comment: No, the problem was the order of the objects in the file. My `Test` object was before `DoSomething`.